# Why is this blurred images not working as a background?

Tags: transparency, background, contrast

How can I get the picture in the background and add a blur to it so it looks like the example ones?

I have tested blur in one of my designs, and it's looks bad x) 
I wonder if it's the color of the font or if I need to add something else.

My image:

[image]

My examples:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The primary difference it the logo artwork. The "nature" logo has no inner-art transparencies, or negatives, so it is *never* going to appear like your 2 top examples, which have negative areas to allow the background to show through the logo itself.

Comment: I gave this question a minus point because I felt that the question is poorly worded and you are not even trying to elaborate it. --- When people answer in a way that doesn't help you, **your** responsibility is to comment and explain what it is that you actually want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem you're having is that both your logo and background are in focus.

You need to take the background out of focus; so blur the background image. Also the path/trail in your background image clashes with the white of your logo.

Secondly, your logo is a little too obtrusive. Make it a bit smaller to expose more of the background image.

Here's an example of your logo with a more "consistent" (colours and tone) image that's been put out of focus, plus a smaller logo that has 90% opacity so it sits more naturally (no pun intended) against the background image.

Hope this gives you some ideas!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your background is too busy (shapes and colors). Try either blurring it a lot or making it black and white. Maybe also reduce the contrast.

Also, on both examples you show, the logos have a very faint shadow. When doing your drop shadow, just don't put any distance so it shows from all sides of the type. Make it big and quite transparent. This should do the trick!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking how to blur you current image and make it look good. As others have pointed out, the picture and logo you are trying to use aren't going to look at good as the examples you selected. It looks like those pictures were taken with a blurred focus for artistic affect, and you'll never be able to replicate that perfectly after the fact. However, you can get a [decent blur from a program like Photoshop](http://layersmagazine.com/field-blur-in-photoshop-cc.html).

It's important you understand the different types of blur available and what they are intended to do. Learning about [blurring images in Photoshop](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/adjusting-image-sharpness-blur.html) might be a good place to start